# Sort collection by multiple fields in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have a list of People which I need to sort by Age first and then by Name.

Coming from a C#-background, I can easily achieve this in said language by using LINQ:

```cs
var list=new List<Person>();
list.Add(new Person(25, "Tom"));
list.Add(new Person(25, "Dave"));
list.Add(new Person(20, "Kate"));
list.Add(new Person(20, "Alice"));

//will produce: Alice, Kate, Dave, Tom
var sortedList=list.OrderBy(person => person.Age).ThenBy(person => person.Name).ToList();
```

How does one accomplish this using Kotlin?

This is what I tried (it's obviously wrong since the output of the first "sortedBy" clause gets overridden by the second one which results in a list sorted by Name only)

```java
val sortedList = ArrayList(list.sortedBy { it.age }.sortedBy { it.name })) //wrong
```

Comment: I too, come from the world of C# and had this same question; thank you for asking it!

Answer (score 650, accepted):

[`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) + [`compareBy`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) (taking a vararg of lambdas) do the trick:

```
val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.age }, { it.name }))
```

You can also use the somewhat more succinct callable reference syntax:

```
val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy(Person::age, Person::name))
```

Comment: In Kotlin 1.2.42 both solutions give the compile error: `Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference: public fun <T> compareBy(vararg selectors: (???) → Comparable<*>?): kotlin.Comparator<???> defined in kotlin.comparisons
public fun <T> compareBy(vararg selectors: (T) → Comparable<*>?): kotlin.Comparator<T> /* = java.util.Comparator<T> */ defined in kotlin.comparisons`

Comment: @arslancharyev31 [This seems to be reported as a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20406). It only shows up in the IDE; my `gradle build` succeeds.

Comment: This is sorting in ascending order,  how to sort in descending order?

Comment: @Chandrika `compareByDescending`

Comment: `compareByDescending` would reverse all the functions. If you just wanna use one field for descending order, slap a `-` (minus) in front, like so `{-it.age}`

Comment: What is "it" in the solution? Is it some sort of keyword? I cannot figure this out. Would be great if someone clarifies this. Thanks!

Comment: @Alkis Mavridis Please see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter

Comment: here is an example of how to implement this https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/4qlomldkm9pvjac0b5vb8j78v0/ev5h81c29ph8rmkf9udb7nb93j

Comment: What if I want a bit more customized comparison, that requires more than the value, but really need the 2 values to compare by?

Comment: in addition to Abhijit Sarkar's answer. If field type is boolean, use `!`

Answer (score 223):

Use [`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) to sort a list with `Comparator`.

You can then construct a comparator using several ways:

- [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html), [`thenBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/then-by.html) construct the comparator in a chain of calls:

  ```
  list.sortedWith(compareBy<Person> { it.age }.thenBy { it.name }.thenBy { it.address })
  ```
- [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) has an overload which takes multiple functions:

  ```
  list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.age }, { it.name }, { it.address }))
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! I'm a bit new to kotlin, why do you need to have `compareBy<Person>` as opposed to just `compareBy` in your first bullet point?

Comment: @Aneem, the Kotlin compiler is sometimes unable to infer the type argument, and that needs to be specified manually. One such case is when a generic type is expected, and you want to pass the result of generic functions calls chain, like `compareBy<Person> { it.age }.thenBy { it.name }.thenBy { it.address }`. In the second point, there's only one function call, no calls chaining: `compareBy({ it.age }, { it.name }, { it.address })`.

Comment: How to add Case Insensitive to that?

Comment: Have u got the solution? @Konrad

Comment: @KoustuvGanguly maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284130/how-to-sort-list-of-objects-by-two-properties-and-collator

Comment: here is an example of how to implement this https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/4qlomldkm9pvjac0b5vb8j78v0/ev5h81c29ph8rmkf9udb7nb93j

Comment: @epool Your link shows an empty playground.