# How to sort objects list in case insensitive order?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have a list of Strings in Kotlin:  `stringList: MutableList<String>`

Then it is is easy to sort such list in case insensitive order by doing this:

```
stringList.sortWith(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```

But how would I sort a list of objects in case insensitive order? For example: `places: MutableList<Place>`

Where `Place` is a simple class with 2 fields - `name: String` and `id: Int`, and I would like to sort these Places by the `name` field.

I tried to do something like this: `places.sortedWith(compareBy { it.name })` but this solution doesn't take letter case into account.

Comment: You can use this reference link : https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-of-object-sort-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It looks like compareBy might be able to take a Comparator as an argument, see the documentation here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html

Try:

```
places.sortWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, { it.name }))
```

or

```
places.sortWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, Place::name))
```

to sort the list in place, or you can assign it to a new variable using

```
val newList = places.sortedWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, { it.name }))
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: FYI `places.sortedWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) { it.name })` works the same and is how a final lambda parameter is usually written. `places.sortedWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, Place::name))` could also be written.

Comment: How to do this case insensitive order for two fields? So e.g first for it.name and then it.last name?

Comment: @ephemient How to do this case insensitive order for two fields? So e.g first for it.name and then  it.last name?

Comment: @K.Os looks like compareBy can take a varargs of lambdas, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259451/346912

Comment: "Note that this Comparator does not take locale into account, and will result in an unsatisfactory ordering for certain locales." - from method description. ```toLowerCase()``` lets you pass in a Locale.

Comment: I found out the hard way that [`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) returns a new instance of the sorted array, while [`sortWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-with.html) sorts the array in place. Given the lack of an assignment, that was deceiving in the original answer.

Comment: Is there a way to do this when you want to sort descending rather than ascending?

Comment: @Adam Burley, To sort descending just use compareByDescending insted of compareBy.

Answer (score 18):

Sort Ascending - case insensitive:

```
myList.sortedBy { it.name?.toLowerCase() }
```

Sort Descending - case insensitive:

```
myList.sortedByDescending { it.name?.toLowerCase() }
```

Comment: How to do this case insensitive order for two fields? So e.g first for it.name and then it.last name?

Comment: thank you! the accepted answer does not give any clue how to sort descending