# How to sort in descending order using multiple comparison fields in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin allows me to sort ASC and array using multiple comparison fields.

For example:

```
return ArrayList(originalItems)
    .sortedWith(compareBy({ it.localHits }, { it.title }))
```

But when I try sort DESC (`compareByDescending()`), it does not allow me to use multiple comparison fields.

Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You could use the `thenByDescending()` (or `thenBy()` for ascending order) extension function to define a secondary `Comparator`.

Assuming `originalItems` are of `SomeCustomObject`, something like this should work:

```
return ArrayList(originalItems)
        .sortedWith(compareByDescending<SomeCustomObject> { it.localHits }
                .thenByDescending { it.title })
```

(of course you have to replace `SomeCustomObject` with your own type for the generic)

Comment: Sweet! It works like a charm. Thank you very much, @earthw0rmjim!

Comment: Here is an even more elegant solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259159/sort-collection-by-multiple-fields-in-kotlin, ```val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareByDescending({ it.age }, { it.name }))```

Answer (score 10):

You can also just use sort ASC and then reverse it:

```
return ArrayList(originalItems).sortedWith(compareBy({ it.localHits }, { it.title })).asReversed()
```

The implementation of the `asReversed()` is a view of the sorted list with reversed index and has better performance than using `reverse()`

Comment: or like this: invoicesList = invoicesList.sortedBy({ it.dt }).reversed()

Answer (score 6):

```
ArrayList(originalItems)
    .sortedWith(compareByDescending({ it.localHits }, { it.title }))
```

You only need to define this function:

```
fun <T> compareByDescending(vararg selectors: (T) -> Comparable<*>?): Comparator<T> {
    return Comparator { b, a -> compareValuesBy(a, b, *selectors) }
}
```

Or you may use the `Comparator` directly:

```
ArrayList(originalItems)
    .sortedWith(Comparator { b, a -> compareValuesBy(a, b, { it.localHits }, { it.title }) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Reversing the comparator also works:

```
originalItems.sortedWith(compareBy<Item>({ it.localHits }, { it.title }).reversed())
```