# Create dynamic sorting Comparator builder from API return

Tags: android, function, kotlin, closures

I have a problem that I really cannot solve.. Maybe You may help me. I need to sort an object list from API return that contains filters. The problem is those filters are dynamic, The object Order (the problematic filter) :

```
class Order(val field : String, val direction: String)
```

The field is an object attribute (column), the direction can be ASC or DESC.
The JSON can return more than one filter, so this can be :

```
order : {
    field : "id",
    direction : "ASC"
        },
        {
    field : "creationDate"
    direction : "DESC"
        }
```

The problem is, I don't know how to create a dynamic function that can create a perfect sort in my list. I know I've got to do this :

```
return list.sortedWith(compareBy(List::id).thenByDescending(List::creationDate))
```

But Dynamically.. wow

KT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the second ordering oly applies to those where the first is the same value
[`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) + [`compareBy`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html)

`compareBy` takes a vararg of selectors which is just a array, so it can be constructed

```
val selectors: Array<(T) -> Comparable<*>?> = orders.map { TODO() }.toArray()
list.sortedWith(compareBy(*selectors))
```

i am thinking some extra function go go though all possible fields you could sort and uses either `it.field` or `-(it.field)` to create the selectors

also see this answer: [Sort collection by multiple fields in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259159/sort-collection-by-multiple-fields-in-kotlin/37259451#37259451)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a map from a property name to the comparator that compares orders by that property:

```
    val comparators = mapOf<String, Comparator<Order>>(
            "field" to compareBy { it.field },
            "direction" to compareBy { it.direction }
    )
```

Then you can pick comparators from that map by the given property names, change their sorting order with `Comparator.reversed()` extension function, and finally combine all these comparators into the single resulting comparator with `Comparator.then(Comparator)` function:

```
    val givenOrder = listOf("field" to "ASC", "direction" to "DESC")

    val resultingOrder = givenOrder
        .map { (fieldName, direction) -> 
            comparators[fieldName]!!.let { if (direction == "DESC") it.reversed() else it }
        }
        .reduce { order, nextComparator -> order.then(nextComparator) } 

    val sortedList = list.sortedWith(resultingOrder)
```